# Phoenix - submitting a form from the client-side and preventing the page from reloading

Tags: ajax, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a form in my pug template that works and gets submitted normally using my Phoenix controller's submit function. I don't want to reload or redirect the page, so I figured I should use an AJAX request to submit the form.

This is the form:

```
=form_for @invoice_changeset, adaptive_invoice_path(@conn, :update, @adaptive, @invoice), [as: :invoice, method: :put, id: 'add-invoice-remarks-form'], fn f ->
  .form-group
    .label Remarks
    = textarea f, :remarks, id: "remarks-area", role: "add-invoice-remarks", class: "textarea", placeholder: "Add Notes here (enter to submit)"
  .form-group
    = submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block"
```

This is the function in my controller that handles the submission of the form. It works normally, but refreshes the page.

```
def update(%Plug.Conn{assigns: %{adaptive: adaptive}} = conn, %{
      "id" => id,
      "invoice" => invoice_params
    }) do
  {:ok, invoice} = Billing.find_invoice(%{"id" => id})

  case Billing.update_invoice(invoice, invoice_remarks) do
    {:ok, invoice} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Invoice update successful!")
      |> redirect(to: adaptive_invoice_path(conn, :show, adaptive, invoice))

    {:error, _changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "Something went wrong while adding remarks!")
      |> redirect(to: adaptive_invoice_path(conn, :show, adaptive, invoice))
  end
end
```

I tried to intercept the form, and submit it with AJAX and [onmount](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onmount), but I receive a `Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError` upon clicking the submit button even though I have the correct route.

```
import { post } from '../../api'

onmount('[role="add-invoice-remarks"]', function () {
  const $form = $('#add-invoice-remarks-form')
  $form.on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const action = $form.attr('action')

    const invoiceParams = {
      remarks: $form.find('#remarks-area').val()
    }

    post(
      action,
      {
        invoice: invoiceParams
      },
      _ => {
        show_flash(success_content())
      },
      response => {
        show_flash(fail_content(response))
      }
    )
  })
})
```

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: @mudasobwa `[debug] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for POST /adaptives/6/invoices/3 (Enterprise.Router)`

Comment: Let me guess: your pipeline accepts html only `plug :accepts, ["html"]` and you do not have a pipeline that handles `json`, right?

Comment: @mudasobwa Okay, I added that in my pipeline, and I still get the same error. If I get rid of the javascript part altogether, I don't get any errors and the controller works as intended, so it can't be the server-side that's causing the problem. However, I still need to prevent the page from refreshing.

Comment: Of course it’s the server part. You should explicitly handle this route when the frontend sends JSON and respond _with a JSON_ back.

Comment: What's your javascript API post look like. Are you sure it's sending 'Content-Type: application/json' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a POST request to a route that's expecting a PUT request.

You need a `_method="put"` parameter in your in addition to your invoice params.

Something like:

```
{
  invoice: invoiceParams,
  _method: "put"
}
```